# Add new last number automatically mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this id number in one column of my table,

```
0907003
0907004 
0907005

1008005 
1008006
1008007

1009001 
1009002
1009003
```

When I add new value of `1009`,  it will add last three number of `004` because the last number begin with `1009` (10-09) is `003`.

Or if I add new value of `1008`, it will add last three number of `008`
because the last number begin with `1008` (10-08) is `007`.

Or if I add new value of `0907`, it will add last three number of `006`
because the last number begin with `0907` (09-07) is `007`.

How to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

```
$front_id = $this->input->post('gameid'); //09
$middle_id = $this->input->post('netid'); //07

//$last_id will be generate automatically by sql 

$forID = $front_id.$middle_id; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO table ('colum') VALUES (".$forID.")"
```

Comment: Can you post some code or explain better what you want to achieve ?!

Comment: What code do you use to insert rows? It is probably better to do it in your php code using a counter table with one row for each prefix and the last number the counter has. With a trigger on insert on the table you described or some php code you can get the result easily

Comment: I want to add last_id automatically which will incrementation from an existing id in the table.

Comment: I just want a simple solution.

Comment: come on, where is people's idea? lol

Comment: What happens at 1008999?

Comment: @strawbery, that's it, I want it to be auto increment. The numbers are separated into three parts, front-middle-last. all parts of number has unpredictable lengths,

Comment: myisam supports multiple auto_increment fields as a composite pk. you can abuse this to do what you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to insert new id manually

```
    $max_of_letsay1009 = mysql_result(mysql_query("select MAX(id) from table where id like '1009%'"),0);

    // get the last 3 digits
    $new_number = (int)substr($max_of_letsay1009,-3) + 1;
```

or you can try this too:

```
    $new_id_of_letsay1009 = mysql_result(mysql_query("select MAX(id)+1 from table where id like '1009%'"),0);
```

this is just my idea, not yet tested and no error checking

Answer (score 1):

You try this below query

If your value is 1009

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT(ID,4))+1 FROM TableName WHERE LEFT(ID,4) = '1009'
```

It will return the max number of that series.

Try this query for dynamic ID length

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT(ID,len(id)-LEN('1009')))+1 FROM #TEMP WHERE LEFT(ID,LEN('1009')) = '1009'
```

You can also use this query as sub query for the insert statement's ID column.

Comment: Actually this is what I want, because I can use it as insert statement directly. However, the length of the number in the front is unpredictable. it can be hundreds, thousand, or millions. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: the above query may meets your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if it is not Auto_Increment coulmn.

Just need to write logic on insert time.

Comment: I want a simple solution. any idea?